# Почему в ходе программы список изменяется

Tags: python-3.x

```
force = []
a = 1
while len(bank_1) > 0 and len(bank_2) > 0:
    if turn == 1:
        first_player_turn()
    else:
        second_player_turn()
    if a % 2 == 1:
        force_attack = force
    else:
        print(force_attack)
        print(force)
    a += 1
    force.clear()
```

проблема в том что force_attack и force должны быть разными и принимают значения input, но когда нужно вывести force_attack программа обновляет этот список до force. Почему так происходит и как сделать так чтобы force_attack сохранило своё первое значение?

Answer (score 2):

Потому что переменные `force` и `force_attack` ссылаются на один и тот же объект.

```
if a % 2 == 1:
    force_attack = force.copy()
```